# How can I transform a line into two and rotate with css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to have a straight line in my header, and then a few seconds after the page loads, I want those lines to slowly move down until they look like the one in the image below:

[image]

I thought of using css transform property to rotate two rotate two divs, but that does not seem to be a solution as you can see the result in my pen [here](https://codepen.io/melodiacapoeira/pen/qzBjvN)

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="big">
  <div class="arrow-box">
    <div class="line line-1"></div>    
    <div class="line line-2"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#big{
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
}
.arrow-box{
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 10px;

}
.line{
  background: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 1px;
}

.line-1{
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.line-2{
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
```

How can I make a/the line look like the icon on the image after the page loads?

Comment: You need to shift your origin of rotation, that's it, `transform-origin: 0 100%;`

Comment: @Justinas Mind sending a working snippet for more clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using css animation. You could use `rotateZ` transform to create arrow shape and also `scale` to keep increasing width of the lines as animation goes.

You also need to use `transform-origin` for both parts to transform at the right point.

```css
.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.line:after,
.line:before {
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.line:before {
  left: 0;
  animation: moveBefore 1s linear forwards;
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.line:after {
  right: 0;
  animation: moveAfter 1s linear forwards;
  transform-origin: center right;
}

@keyframes moveBefore {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(15deg) scale(1.05, 1);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(30deg) scale(1.16, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes moveAfter {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateZ(-15deg) scale(1.05, 1);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(-30deg) scale(1.16, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

You could also do this with `svg` using `line` element and some javascript to move `y` position left and right line parts. To increase angle gradually you can use `setInterval` method.

```js
let step = 0;
const left = document.querySelector('.left-line');
const right = document.querySelector('.right-line');

function move(el, prop, size) {
  el.setAttribute(prop, +el.getAttribute(prop) + size);
}

setInterval(() => {
  if (step <= 40) {
    move(left, 'y2', 0.8);
    move(right, 'y1', 0.8)
    step += 1;
  }
}, 30)
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <line class="left-line" x1="0" y1="20" x2="40" y2="20" stroke="black" />
  <line class="right-line" x1="40" y1="20" x2="80" y2="20" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: @deSousa You can customize animation more as you want by using percentages https://jsfiddle.net/q4anj80L/

Comment: Do you have a great css animation reference course?

Comment: Not really, maybe take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer works just fine the artist in me can't take the overlapping of the lines in the center due to the scaling. Here's a few alternate options:

#### Option 1 - `clip-path`

Using clip-path, animate the mid-points of a rectangle to transform the polygon into a chevron. This works by masking the background color of the element outside of the animated shape.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 2px, 0 2px);
  animation: 2s infinite linear;
}

.line.down {
  animation-name: chevron-down;
}

.line.up {
  animation-name: chevron-up;
}

@keyframes chevron-down {
  from {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 0, 100% 0, 100% 2px, 50% 2px, 0 2px);
  }
  to {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 48px, 100% 0, 100% 2px, 50% 50px, 0 2px);
  }
}

@keyframes chevron-up {
  from {
    clip-path: polygon(0 48px, 50% 48px, 100% 48px, 100% 50px, 50% 50px, 0 50px);
  }
  to {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 48px, 100% 0, 100% 2px, 50% 50px, 0 2px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line down"></div>
<div class="line up"></div>
```

Support for [`clip-path`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) is spotty, however.

---

#### Option 2 - pseudo-elements

If you can't use `clip-path` or prefer to use pseudo elements, change their placement and origins of transform to come from the center (and not the upper corners):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.line::before,
.line::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  animation: 2s linear infinite;
}

.line::before {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  left: 0;
  animation-name: before;
}
.line::after {
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  right: 0;
  animation-name: after;
}

@keyframes before {
  to { transform: rotateZ(30deg); }
}

@keyframes after {
  to { transform: rotateZ(-30deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```